# how to get tuples from lists using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have two lists and want to merges them into one list of `tuples`. I want to do it with `list comprehension`, I can get it working using `map`. but would be nice to know how list comprehension here will work.
code here

```
>>> lst =  [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> lst2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> tup = map(None,lst,lst2) # works fine
>>> tup
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
>>> l3 = [lst, lst2]
>>> l3
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> zip(*l3) # works fine
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]

>>> [(i,j) for i in lst and for j in lst2] # does not work
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [(i,j) for i in lst and for j in lst2]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I have written comments where it works and where it does not. How can a two `for-loop` be coupled in `list comprehension`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think about list comprehensions as loops. How can you write 2 not nested loops?

You can do this with somewhat wierd list comprehension:

```
[(x, lst2[i]) for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
```

or

```
[(lst[i], lst2[i]) for i in xrange(len(lst))]
```

But actually, it's better to use `zip`.

Comment: nice solution, I was wondering if and how to get two for loops inside list comprehension

Answer (score 7):

The list comprehension way is silly, because it just wraps a do-nothing list comprehension around `zip`:

```
[(i,j) for i, j in zip(lst, lst2)]
```

Just use `zip`, this is what it's for.  There's no sense in forcing yourself to use list comprehensions when they don't accomplish anything.

Edit: If your question is "how do I get two for loops in one list comprehension", you should ask that instead.  The answer is "You can't get two PARALLEL `for` loops in one list comprehension".  Any time you put two `for` clauses in a list comprehension, they will be nested.  That, a list comprehension like this:

```
[... for a in list1 for b in list2]
```

Works like two nested `for` loops:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        ...
```

You can't write a list comprehension that does this:

```
for a in list1:
    ...
for b in list2:
    ...
```

. . . and you don't need to, because you have the `zip` function to do that instead.

(You can sort of fake it using a solution like @Roman Pekar's, but that doesn't really do two `for` loops; it just does one and uses the values from that one to reach into the other list.)

Comment: This is equivalent to using zip(lst, lst2). There is no need for [(i,j) for i, j in zip(lst, lst2)] >>> `zip(lst, lst2)
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
>>> [(i,j) for i, j in zip(lst, lst2)]
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]` I would like to achieve this without using `zip`if possible

Comment: @user2708477 why don't you want to use zip?

Comment: @RomanPekar: as my question says I want to use list comprehension, simply because I want to see how to get two for-loops inside list comprehension, I do know how zip works though and it is fairly straightforward to use with zip

Comment: @user2708477 as I see it, list comprehensions is basically shorthand for loops. How can you write 2 not nested loops?

Comment: @user2708477: See my edited answer.  The answer is that you cannot get two non-nested loops into one list comprehension.

Comment: Why unpack `i,j`? `[t for t in zip(lst, lst2)]`